# How to copy cms page data created using pagebuilder from lower environment to upper environment?

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I am creating a page in my local environment. Once its completely developed I would want to have same page created on upper environment i.e UAT environment in my case and later on pre-prod and production environment as well.

I can not keep on creating pages in pagebuilder from scratch as I have multiple pages and multiple environments to work on.
Is there a way I can copy the code from magento admin from one environment and paste it on another?

Also for bulk pages is there a way to export from lower environment and import on upper environments?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. Try to avoid 3rd party modules as well. I try like this:

1. Transfer SQL from env to env. Copy the latest content from production to local. Modify and transfer full CMS page related table to any env

OR

1. Create a setup installer that will create/update your cms page during code deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna try another page builder tool, may I suggest this [Magento Page Builder](https://github.com/Goomento/PageBuilder), all the headache of original builder will be gone